# CSS Apply white space left and right of the table content

Tags: html, css

i want to design a table that looks like the table in the image.

[Table example](http://tinypic.com/r/33y1477/5)

I could aply the space using empy tags and then using css so they became white but code like that is ugly.

This is what i have in the moment:

```
<table id="specs">
    <tr>                           
        <th class="thead" >A</th>
        <th class="thead">B</th>
        <th class="thead">C</th>
        <th class="thead">D</th>
        <th class="thead">E</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="type2">1</td>
        <td class="type">2</td>
        <td class="type">3</td>
        <td class="type"> 4</td>
        <td class="type">5%</td>
        <td class="type" style="border-top:10px solid white;">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="type2">7</td>
        <td class="type">8</td>
        <td class="type">9</td>
        <td class="type">10</td>
        <td class="type">11</td>
        <td class="type">12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#specs {
    color: #0099FF;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#specs th {
    background-color: #0099FF;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}
#specs tr.alt td {
    background-color: #C0D9D9;
}

#specs th.thead {
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#specs tr td.type2 {
    border-left: 10px solid white;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first well form your table:

```
<table id="specs">
  <thead>
        <tr>

            <th class="thead" >A</th>
            <th class="thead">B</th>
            <th class="thead">C</th>
            <th class="thead">D</th>
            <th class="thead" colspan="2">E</th>

        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

        <tr class="alt">

            <td class="type2">1</td>
            <td class="type">2</td>
            <td class="type">3</td>
            <td class="type"> 4</td>
            <td class="type">5%</td>
            <td class="type" >6</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="type2">7</td>
            <td class="type">8</td>
            <td class="type">9</td>
            <td class="type">10</td>
            <td class="type">11</td>
            <td class="type">12</td>

        </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

It will give some meaning to your table and will make it easier to style .
try this for instance : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dilzg

Answer (score 0):

To add a white space of 2px under each row, you just have to add a border using css, for example like this :

```
tr {
    border-bottom : 2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `border-left` and `border-right` onto your `td` though make sure you don't style the `tr` as that never works:

```
td:first {
    border-left : 10px solid #ffffff;
}
td:last {
    border-right : 10px solid #ffffff;
}
```